# "In presupposing" or "in that they presuppose"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Is it better to write *The theories are unique in that they presuppose ...*, or *The theories are unique in presupposing ...*?

Comment: both are correct; which is "better" is a matter of opinion. Note that we don't do "proofreading" questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are grammatically correct and idiomatic. Their meaning is close to the same. The only difference is where they place the emphasis:

> The theories are unique in that they presuppose XYZ

This suggests that the theories are unique (compared to some group, e.g. other theories in the same field), and that their presupposition of XYZ is what makes them unique. The emphasis is on the uniqueness of the theories *in and of themselves*.

> The theories are unique in presupposing XYZ

This suggests that the theories are the only ones that presuppose XYZ (again out of some group, e.g. other theories in the same field), and that this fact makes them unique. The emphasis is on the uniqueness of the theories *in virtue of the presupposition*.

However the difference is quite minor, and both are save to use in all contexts where either is appropriate.